# validation on image upload in android studio

Tags: android, image, validation

Hi i am trying to upload image in sqllite database. And it is working fine. Problem i am facing if i don't select any image program crash. I want to show "*please select image*" if user don't select image from gallery. How can i give that validation?? Here is my code:

**BlogActivity.java**

```
public class BlogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnSaveRecord;
    Button btnfullinfo;
    Button btnNewUser;
    EditText editFirstName;
    EditText editLastName;

    Button btnSaveImage;
    ImageView showImage;


    EditText editWeb;

    DatabaseManager databaseManager;
    Blog blog = new Blog();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.blog_activity);

        btnSaveRecord = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSaveRecord);
        editFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editFirstName);
        editLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editLastName);
        btnSaveImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSaveImage);
        editWeb = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editWeb);
        showImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.showImage);

        databaseManager = new DatabaseManager(BlogActivity.this);


        if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
            blog = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("Blog");
//                Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, user.get_first_name(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            editFirstName.setText(blog.get_title());
            editLastName.setText(blog.getBlog_desc());
            editWeb.setText(blog.getBlog_link());
            showImage.setImageBitmap(convertToBitmap(blog.getBlog_image()));

        }


        btnSaveImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSaveImage);
        btnSaveImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                loadImageGallery();

            }
        });
        btnfullinfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnfullinfo);
        btnfullinfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(BlogActivity.this, BloglistActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        btnSaveRecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Bitmap bitmap = resize(((BitmapDrawable) showImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap(), 512, 512);


                blog.setBlog_tilte(editFirstName.getText().toString());
                blog.setBlog_desc(editLastName.getText().toString());
                blog.setBlog_image(convertToBase64(bitmap));
                blog.setBlog_link(editWeb.getText().toString());
                if (blog.getBlog_ID() == 0) {
                    databaseManager.addBlog(blog);
                } else {
                    databaseManager.updateBlog(blog);
                }


                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(BlogActivity.this, "Blog Added Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        });

        btnNewUser = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNewUser);
        btnNewUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //loadImageGallery();
                editFirstName.setText("");
                editLastName.setText("");
                showImage.setImageBitmap(null);
                editWeb.setText("");
                blog = new Blog();
            }
        });
    }

    public void loadImageGallery() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 1);
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        String fileSelected = null;

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            /** Get File from Gallery**/
            try {
                InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                showImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Toast.makeText(BlogActivity.this, "Working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public String convertToBase64(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, os);
        byte[] byteArray = os.toByteArray();
        return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, 0);
    }

    public Bitmap convertToBitmap(String base64String) {
        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(base64String, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap bitmapResult = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
        return bitmapResult;
    }


    private Bitmap resize(Bitmap originalImage, int width, int height) {
        Bitmap background = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) width, (int) height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        float originalWidth = originalImage.getWidth(), originalHeight = originalImage.getHeight();
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(background);
        float scale = width / originalWidth;
        float xTranslation = 0.0f, yTranslation = (height - originalHeight * scale) / 2.0f;
        Matrix transformation = new Matrix();
        transformation.postTranslate(xTranslation, yTranslation);
        transformation.preScale(scale, scale);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        canvas.drawBitmap(originalImage, transformation, paint);
        originalImage.recycle();
        return background;
    }

    //Actiobar Menu Item

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        //         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        MenuInflater inflater = this.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.appmenu, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.idblog:
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BloglistActivity.class));
                return true;
            case R.id.idShowquiz:
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), QuizActivity.class));
                return true;
            case R.id.idaddblogs:
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BlogActivity.class));
                return true;
            case R.id.idlinks:
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LinkActivity.class));
                return true;
            case R.id.idShowportfolio:
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PersonlistActivity.class));
                return true;
            case R.id.idaddportfolio:
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PersonActivity.class));
                return true;
            case R.id.idaddContact:
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ContactActivity.class));
                return true;
            case R.id.idsms:
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SmsActivity.class));
                return true;
            case R.id.idlogout:
//                Toast.makeText(this, " Log Out ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); // this will clear all the stack
                intent.putExtra("Exit me", true);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

**blog_activity.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/showImage"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
    <!--android:src="@drawable/placeholder"-->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSaveImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#f66565"
        android:text="Select Image" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editFirstName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Blog Title">

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editLastName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter Blog Description" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editWeb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter Web Link">

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNewUser"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="#f66565"
            android:text="New Blog" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSaveRecord"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="#f66565"
            android:text="Save Blog" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnfullinfo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="#f66565"
            android:text="Show All" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually pick an image this way and I don't get any problem :

```
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            i.setType("image/*");

            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);¸

    //...

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        Toast.makeText(c, "ON ACTIVITY RESULT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            try {

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

                String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePath, null, null, null);

                c.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);

                String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);

                c.close();

                Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

                saveImage(thumbnail);

            }

            catch(Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(e), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    }
```

What cause the error ? Are you pressing the back button or selecting an other file type ?

Comment: its always shows null pointer exception if i  press save without selecting any image.

Comment: So what are you selecting ? Nothing because you push the back button ?

Comment: this is my insert form. If i don't select any image and save my form its throwing null pointer exception. I guess it can't save any empty strings. That is why i want to show a message if user forget to select any image and press message will show "Please insert image"

Comment: You set fileSelected to null and you do not change it...set it to "" to avoid null pointer exception

Comment: Also the Intent delivered in onActivityResult gives informations about the selected image. Look at the sample code I sent. A if statement should be added to alert user if no image file was selected

Comment: can you please update my code?? i was trying to change as you say but its not working...same exception. And i also have my try catch on if statement. if file is not selected it should throw file not found exception on catch statement but its not doing that.

Comment: My code is up and running. Create your own saveImage() function to insert in database. The only missing part is where you should compare string to "" and show a toast.

Comment: thanx for the suggestion :)

Comment: I will check this out tomorrow. I am running  out of time actually. I'll keep in touch with you and this topic and send a complete solution in a few hours, if needed. But you are not far from your solution